# Is there an option to influence WhatsApp display text direction instead of automatically according to the language?

Tags: whatsapp, right-to-left, hebrew

When starting with Latin characters and continuing with Hebrew characters, WhatsApp shows the paragraph in left-to-right, where the intention is right-to-left.
Is there a way to "tell" the recipient device what is the desired paragraph direction?

Answer (score 1):

In a computer you should be able to inset LRM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) to force the toolkit to render in LTR mode. I am unsure how is this implemented on each of the platforms WhatsApp works (HTML, Android and IOS).